# How to display string svg file in jetpack compose?

Tags: image, kotlin, svg, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to display string svg file in jetpack compose . Firstly I tried AsyncImage like that :

**example image file :**

```
 {
    ...
    "image": "https://aaa.com/static/img/breakfast.svg"
 },
```

**what I did:**

```
Image(
       painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = mealImage),
       contentDescription = "",
       modifier = Modifier.size(150.dp).padding(5.dp)
     )
```

I did it like that but it didn't display. How can I display the string svg file in my jetpack compose project ? Isn't it supposed to be this way ?